# Getting all the words of a string in to an array?

Tags: php, html

I have a string as follows:
`is newegg.com a scam ? – fraudwatchers`

When I put that string in to an array, using the following code:

```
$title_word = str_word_count(“is newegg.com a scam ? – fraudwatchers”, 1);
```

It gives me the following results:

```
  0 => string 'is' (length=2)
  1 => string 'newegg' (length=6)
  2 => string 'com' (length=3)
  3 => string 'a' (length=1)
  4 => string 'scam' (length=4)
  5 => string '-' (length=1)
  6 => string 'fraudwatchers' (length=13)
```

I would like one array element to contain the whole world `“newegg.com”` and another array element to contain `“?”` Can you please tell me how I can do this with an example. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Updated:
if I use `explode(' ', $my_text);` This does not work correctly. if I were to go through a body of a web page, it assign few words to one array element with new lines.
(I need none words in my array as well).

Comment: Before start you must define 'word'. '-' does not looks like a word.

Comment: is empty space between words good separator for you? so array with "is","newegg.com","a","scam" is ok?

Comment: May I assume the `-` should also be a word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, you can try following:

```
$sentence = 'is newegg.com a scam ? - fraudwatchers';
$words = explode(' ', $sentence);
```

A little more advanced answer - this one will handle all white characters such as tabs and newlines:

```
$words = preg_split("/\s+/", $sentence);
```

If you need to filter out non-words, you can also use `array_filter`. Note that this won't handle non-latin words.

```
$words = array_filter($words, function($word) { return preg_match('/^\w+$/', $word); });
```

For multilingual word matching, you can check [Unicode character properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) article.

Comment: Thank you so much for showing me with an example. what I was looking for was `preg_split`. I really apriciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you just mean:

```
$words = explode(" ", "is newegg.com a scam ? – fraudwatchers");
```

Comment: This will also make `-` be a word. Just like the requested `?` and `newegg.com`

Answer (score 0):

use php [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php)

```
$array=explode(" ", $your_text);
```